# Get total amount of fruits each mammal is carring

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am struggling with specific MySQL query based problem.

I have such result set:

```
Table: Report
 mammal_id    mammal_name   fruit_name   gets  |  total  |
    3         rabbit        apple         4    |    5    |
    3         rabbit        carrot        4    |    4    |
    3         rabbit        cabbage       1    |    3    |
    2         squirrel      nuts          1    |    3    |
    2         squirrel      cabbage       2    |    2    |
    1         chipmunk      nuts          2    |    2    |
    1         chipmunk      apple         1    |    1    |

And I want to filter like this:

Table: Filtered
 mammal_id    mammal_name   fruit_name   has  
    3         rabbit        apple         4
    3         rabbit        carrot        4
    3         rabbit        cabbage       1
    2         squirrel      nuts          1
    2         squirrel      cabbage       2
    1         chipmunk      nuts          2
    1         chipmunk      apple         1
```

The hole point is to get total amount of fruits each mammal is carring.

Now I have:

```
SELECT a.mammal_id, b.mammal_id, a.mammal_name, b.mammal_name, a.fruit_name, b.fruit_name, (b.total - a.total) as has
FROM (SELECT * FROM Report (result set)) as a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM Report (result set)) as b 
ON a.fruit_name=b.fruit_name WHERE  a.mammal_id = b.mammal_id-1
```

After this query, I get result like this:

```
Table: Result
a.mammal_id  b.mammal_id  a.mammal_name  b.mammal_name  a.fruit_name  b.fruit_name  has
   2             3            squirrel      rabbit         cabbage        cabbge     1
   1             2            chipmunk      squirrel       nuts           nuts       1
```

Appreciate any guidance on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should give you exactly the output you need.

```
SELECT mammal_id, mammal_name, fruit_name, SUM(gets) as has
FROM Report GROUP BY mammal_name, fruit_name
```

Comment: Thanks! Much easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of items that each animal has in the "gets" column, you want

```
SELECT mammal_id, mammal_name, SUM(gets)
FROM Report 
GROUP BY mammal_id, mammal_name
```

If that's not what you're asking, please clarify the question.